# How to laterally invert images in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to use a sprite sheet, however it only contains images of the character facing right, I want to laterally invert these images when making the character move left. I can't figure out how to do so, if anyone knows how please feel free to let me know!

Comment: What have you tried? How are you storing sprite sheet data? Have you written any code? Are you getting errors?

Comment: This is accomplished with `pygame.transform.flip`, which has an argument that lets you specify a horizontal flip. Have you looked into or tried that? I found plenty of info on it when I googled `pygame horizontal flip`. You haven't provided any info on what you've tried or researched, so it's going to waste our time if we suggest things that you've already attempted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flip an image with [`pygame.transform.flip`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.flip):

```py
flipped_image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 150))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image = pygame.image.load('bird.png').convert_alpha()
flipped_image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = (75, 75)))
    window.blit(flipped_image, flipped_image.get_rect(center = (225, 75)))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```